# React JS - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to show `TopicsList`component when user clicks on `SingleTopicBox` component and hide `SelectedTopicPage` component. However, i'm getting error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` on topic-list.jsx file.

**main-controller.jsx**

```
import {React, ReactDOM} from '../../../build/react';

import TopicsList from '../topic-list.jsx';
import SelectedTopicPage from '../selected-topic-page.jsx';
import topicPages from '../../content/json/topic-pages.js';

export default class MainController extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isTopicClicked: false,
    topicPages
  };

  onClick(topicID) {
    this.setState({isTopicClicked: true});
    this.setState({topicsID: topicID});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        {this.state.isTopicClicked
          ? <SelectedTopicPage topicsID={this.state.topicsID} key={this.state.topicsID} topicPages={topicPages}/>
          : <TopicsList/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

**topic-list.jsx**

```
import {React, ReactDOM} from '../../build/react';

import SingleTopicBox from './single-topic-box.jsx';
import SelectedTopicPage from './selected-topic-page.jsx';
import topicPages from '../content/json/topic-pages.js';

export default class TopicsList extends React.Component {
  onClick(){
    this.props.onClick.bind(null, this.topicID);
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row topic-list">
        <SingleTopicBox topicID="1" onClick={this.onClick} label="Topic"/>
        <SingleTopicBox topicID="2" onClick={this.onClick} label="Topic"/>
        <SingleTopicBox topicID="3" onClick={this.onClick} label="Topic"/>
        <SingleTopicBox topicID="4" onClick={this.onClick} label="Topic"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

**single-topic-box.jsx**

```
import {React, ReactDOM} from '../../build/react';

export default class SingleTopicBox extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-sm-2">
                    <div className="single-topic" data-topic-id={this.props.topicID}>
                        {this.props.label} {this.props.topicID}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several mistakes

1. You should pass `onClick` to `TopicsList`

   ```
   render() {
     return (
       <div className="row">
         {this.state.isTopicClicked
           ? <SelectedTopicPage 
                topicsID={this.state.topicsID} 
                key={this.state.topicsID} 
                topicPages={topicPages} />
           : <TopicsList onClick={ this.onClick.bind(this) } />}
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```
2. remove `onClick` method from `TopicsList`

   ```
    onClick() {
      // ...
    },
   ```
3. pass `onClick` callback from `props`

   ```
   <SingleTopicBox topicID="1" onClick={this.props.onClick} label="Topic"/>
   ```
4. add to `SingleTopicBox` `onClick` event

   ```
   <div 
      className="single-topic" 
      data-topic-id={this.props.topicID} 
      onClick={ () => this.props.onClick(this.props.topicID) }
   >
     {this.props.label} {this.props.topicID}
   </div>
   ```
5. you don't need call `setState` twice

   ```
    onClick(topicID) {
      this.setState({
        isTopicClicked: true, 
        topicsID: topicID
      });
    }
   ```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/pr7zcoa8/)